# Whenever Cron Job "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler, whenever

I got this error while running my cronjob....

my bundle version is 2.1.4

My Task

```
bash -l -c 'cd /Users/crone/Project/WEB/rph-web && bin/rails runner -e development "Bill.send_bill_for_payment" >> log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

My Output

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in 'warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in 'initialize' from /Users/crone/Project/WEB/rph-web/bin/spring:10:in 'new' from /Users/crone/Project/WEB/rph-web/bin/spring:10:in '<top (required)>' from bin/rails:3:in 'load' from bin/rails:3:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails runner` instead of `bin/rails runner`. Sometimes the wrong version of bundler is picked up if you have multiple installed.

Comment: @SiimLiiser I tried using this in my schedule.rb

`job_type :runner, 'cd :path && bundle exec rails runner -e :environment ":task" :output'`